# D3 Choropleth: TypeError: Cannot read property 'counties' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, topojson

I'm following along Mike Bostock's choropleth [tutorial](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-choropleth).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo.v1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>

      </script>
      <style>
         body { font-family: Arial; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <svg></svg>
       <script>

         us = d3.json("https://unpkg.com/us-atlas@1/us/10m.json")

         const width = 960;
         const height = 600;
         const path = d3.geoPath();

         const svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height)
            .style("width", "100%")
            .style("height", "auto");

         //svg-command
         svg.append("g")
         .selectAll("path")
         .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
         .enter().append("path")
         .attr("fill", d => color(data.get(d.id)))
         .attr("d", path)
         .append("title")
         .text(d => format(data.get(d.id)));

         format = d3.format("")     
      </script>             

</html>
```

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'counties' of undefined at check.html:32 (anonymous) @ check.html:32`

My understanding is that the svg-command adds a group element as a child to the svg element. It selects the path variable and binds the counties which are features in the topojson file. The topojson.feature() command converts the data to GEOJson.

All the counties get selected in the enter() command since there is no "g" in the html block. Then, the following commands give each of them a color and a name.

Is topojson.feature still in use?

Comment: topojson.feature is still in use, you aren't passing topojson to it though - if you log `us` you'll see that it isn't topojson (`us` doesn't have a property called objects, hence your error). The issue lies with how you use d3.json - try `d3.json("file", function(error, us) { ... map code ... })` (for v4, v5 would be different).

Comment: Thank you. Your comment made me realize the tutorial uses old d3. I've switched to this and it's working - https://bl.ocks.org/adamjanes/6cf85a4fd79e122695ebde7d41fe327f

Comment: Part of the code says `.tickFormat(function(x, i) { return i ? x : x + "%"; })`. I read the ? is an inline if/then statement. Does this mean: for each indexed value, i, replace x with the concat of x and "%" and then use that new array for the tickformat?

Comment: For the first value, `i == 0`, i is falsey, so it will add a percent sign to the value. For all other indexes, just return the value. In the legend you'll see only the first value has a percent sign.

Comment: So it says, return i, if i is falsy, then replace x with x + "%", else continue and return x

Comment: Other than returning i, yes. Expanding, `i ? x : x + "%"` can be rewritten as `if(i) return x; else return x + "%";`, every value of i other than 0 will be truthy, so this only will modify `x` for the zeroth index.

Comment: @Sebastian This is a ternary operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator